# Is there a class built-in to .NET for querying XML DTD information?

Tags: .net, xml, sdk, schema, dtd

Does .NET provide any built-in support for working with XML DTDs? I want to retrieve element type, attribute lists, and entity declaration information. I'm aware of the support for validating against a DTD, but want to be able to work with the DTD information itself.

I'd be fine parsing DTDs manually to accomplish this, but would rather not if there's already something built-in to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

.Net does have support for DTD

The following link has further information from Microsoft on useage.

[Microsoft DTD Information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379)

Comment: Right, as I mentioned in my question, I'm aware of the .NET support for validating against a DTD. I don't see any way in the framework to get info on the DTD itself, such as available elements, attributes, and entities.